# Nginx: The changes in the configuration file does not seem to work?

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-404

I am new to nginx and i tried a lot to figure out what is going wrong but couldnt.

First, I added a html file `"welcome.html"` in `/usr/share/nginx/html/data/www`. Then I could access it in my browser using, `localhost/data/www/welcome.html`.

Then I added the following code in the nginx.conf file in /etc/bin/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
server
{
    location /
    {
        root /data/www;
    }
}
```

After that, i reloaded the configurations using, sudo nginx -s reload. This gave no errors!

But, after this I tried to access my file using `"localhost/welcome.html"` but it shows an error 404! Although I can still access the file at `"localhost/data/www/welcome.html"`. Please tell me where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use absolute path in `root` directive. So use:

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html/data/www;
```

Also nginx does not reload if it sees errors in config, so check your config with `nginx -t`.

Comment: I added the absolute path. and also checked the config file using nginx -t. It said:nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: I am still not able to access the file that way. It still is available at "localhost/data/www/welcome.html"

Comment: Have you disabled default nginx server block? One in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`.

Comment: Thanks! I did not do that previously, I was following the beginner's guide,and i guess, its not mentioned there, or i missed it. It worked! Thanks a lot :)